# How to setup two virtual hosts in CentOS?

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I have two domains I'm trying to host on the same IP. This is what I've been trying, but it doesn't work:

```
    <VirtualHost host1.me:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@menet.me
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/host1/
        ServerName host1.me
        ErrorLog logs/host1-error_log
        CustomLog logs/host1-access_log common
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost host2.me:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@menet.me
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/host2/
        ServerName www.host2.me
        ServerAlias host2.me
        ErrorLog logs/host2-error_log
        CustomLog logs/host2-access_log common
    </VirtualHost>
```

What should I put in my httpd.conf?

Answer (score 0):

if you are accessing the urls locally i.e. on server itself,
then u need to add their entries in /etc/hosts file.

eg: suppose ur server ip is 192.168.1.1, thn put following entry in hosts file:

192.168.1.1 host1.me host2.me www.host2.me

save the file...

and then check...

hope this helps :)

Comment: Could you, please, show me an example of this file, since I don't even have it on the server. Should I create it?

Comment: And should I still make the changes in the httpd.conf file?

Comment: suppose ur server ip is 192.168.1.1, then put following entry in /etc/hosts

vi /etc/hosts

192.168.1.1 host1.me host2.me www.host2.me localhost

save quit
no need to make changes in httpd.conf